# Zip multiple arrays in PHP based on their identical keys and not their indices or their positions in array

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays:

```
$a = ['one'=>1,'two'=> 2,'three'=> 3,'four'=> 4,'five'=> 5, 'six' => 6];
$b = ['one'=>'uno', 'three'=>'tres','two'=> 'dos', 'four'=>'cuatro', 'five'=>'cinco'];
```

note that in $b Array 'three' and 'two' keys are not in same order as $a. also 'six' key is not available in $b Array.

I want this result as output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => uno
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => dos
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => tres
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 4
            [1] => cuatro
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
            [1] => cinco
        )

)
```

I tried to use array_map but it don't detect keys and just zip them based of their indices:

```
$d = array_map(null, $a, $b);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use [ksort()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php). Then, create a new array using `foreach'?

Comment: good idea! I will try it. but some of the keys may not present in both array always.

Comment: so just use `if(isset(..))` :)

Answer (score 0):

An example using `foreach`

```php
<?php

$a = ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'three' => 3, 'four' => 4, 'five' => 5];
$b = ['one' => 'uno', 'three' => 'tres', 'two' => 'dos', 'four' => 'cuatro', 'five' => 'cinco'];

$output = [];

foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
    $output[] = [$value,  $b[$key]];
}

print_r($output);
```

Comment: values of $b in output are empty

Comment: @KianoushFouladi, [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/deca3811e9ab160a7ddf7b108e43fd4a94203e0d) here. The result is same as your expected output.

Comment: thanks but it need minor modification when keys  in both arrays are not same as each others. (missing key).

Answer (score 0):

modified ikhvjs answer (when keys in both arrays are not same as each others):

```
$a = ['one' => 1, 'two' => 2, 'four' => 4, 'five' => 5, 'six' => 6];
$b = ['one' => 'uno', 'three' => 'tres', 'two' => 'dos', 'four' => 'cuatro', 'five' => 'cinco'];    
$r=array_intersect_key($a,$b);
$output = [];    
foreach ($r as $key => $value) {
    $output[] = [$value,  $b[$key]];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($output);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: You should correct your question as well because this result is not the same as your expected output in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I must say @ikhvjs's answer is the closest to perfect, but the `$b` array doesn't have a value with the key `six`.  To accommodate the possibility of elements in `$b` not relating to elements in `$a`, use the null coalescing operator to fallback to a `null` value.

As for the mentioning of `ksort()`, this will do nothing to accommodate the fact that the input arrays have different lengths / keys.

The use of `array_intersect_key()` will result in `$a` values being omitted where not related to an element in `$b`.

If `$a` is not a reliable "master" array (with all possible keys), then you will need to loop a temporary array formed by merging the two arrays and implement the null coalescing operator on both values to be pushed into the result array.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/QaOnp)) ([Demo of null coalescing on both values](https://3v4l.org/2PUa2))

```
$a = [
    'one' => 1,
    'two' => 2,
    'three' => 3,
    'four' => 4,
    'five' => 5,
    'six' => 6
];
$b = [
    'one' => 'uno',
    'three' => 'tres',
    'two' => 'dos',
    'four' => 'cuatro',
    'five' => 'cinco'
];

$result = [];
foreach ($a as $k => $v) {
    $result[] = [$v, $b[$k] ?? null];
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 'uno',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 'dos',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 'tres',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 4,
    1 => 'cuatro',
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 5,
    1 => 'cinco',
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 6,
    1 => NULL,
  ),
)
```